# How to fix this iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to write an iterator Digits(n) that generates digits of a natural number n in reverse order. Here's my code so far:

```
class Digits:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n < 10:
            return self.n
        return self.n // 10
```

Output should be:

```
>>> print([x for x in Digits(1337)])
[7, 3, 3, 1]
```

I feel I should implement somewhere `self.n % 10` (I hope) , but I don't know where. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, instead of self.n // 10, you should make two calls: self.n /= 10 and return self.n % 10. However, beware of your current solution what doesn't have an end condition (the last digit will be printed indefinetly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```py
class Digits:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        digit = self.n % 10
        self.n  = self.n // 10
        return digit

print([x for x in Digits(1337)])
```

Output:

```
[7, 3, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, now is fine. So, I should add `raise StopIteration`. Does every iterator have some kind of raise?

Comment: Yes, it's always `StopIteration`. Since the `return` is used to signify the value of the step, you have few alternatives to signal the end of the whole thing (another variant would be to return either `None` or a wrapped value).

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: it is rarely preferred to self-implement an iterator with `__next__` instead of a generator with `yield`:

```
def digits(n):
    while n > 10:
        yield n % 10
        n //= 10
    yield n
```

This also relieves you from having to raise `StopIteration` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually modify the value, so don't iterate it. Try something like

```
def __next__(self):
   if self.n == 0:
       raise StopIteration()
   ret_val = self.n % 10
   self.n = //= 10
   return ret_val
```

Comment: When I do this, it never stops.

Comment: Sure, every non-p-adic number turns into zeroes far enough from its least digit. Raise `StopIteration` to not return infinite zero sequence.